# Tight Loop - Disk at 100%, Quad Core CPU @25% useage, only 15MBsec disk write speed

Tags: multithreading, performance, eventstoredb

I have a tight loop which runs through a load of carts, which themselves contain around 10 events event objects and writes them to the disk in JSON via an intermediate repository (jOliver common domain rewired with GetEventStore.com):

```
// create ~200,000 carts, each with ~5 events
List<Cart> testData = TestData.GenerateFrom(products);
foreach (var cart in testData)
{
    count = count + (cart as IAggregate).GetUncommittedEvents().Count;
    repository.Save(cart);
}
```

I see the disk says it is as 100%, but the throughout is 'low' (15MB/sec, ~5,000 events per second) why is this, things i can think of are:

1. Since this is single threaded does the 25% CPU usage actually mean 100% of the 1 core that I am on (any way to show specific core my app is running on in Visual Studio)?
2. Am i constrained by I/O, or by CPU? Can I expect better performance if i create my own thread pool one for each CPU?
3. How come I can copy a file at ~120MB/sec, but I can only get throughput of 15MB/sec in my app? Is this due to the write size of lots of smaller packets?

Anything else I have missed?

[image: throughput]

The code I am using is from the geteventstore docs/blog:

```
public class GetEventStoreRepository : IRepository
{
    private const string EventClrTypeHeader = "EventClrTypeName";
    private const string AggregateClrTypeHeader = "AggregateClrTypeName";
    private const string CommitIdHeader = "CommitId";
    private const int WritePageSize = 500;
    private const int ReadPageSize = 500;

    IStreamNamingConvention streamNamingConvention;

    private readonly IEventStoreConnection connection;
    private static readonly JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None };


    public GetEventStoreRepository(IEventStoreConnection eventStoreConnection, IStreamNamingConvention namingConvention)
    {
        this.connection = eventStoreConnection;
        this.streamNamingConvention = namingConvention;
    }

    public void Save(IAggregate aggregate)
    {
        this.Save(aggregate, Guid.NewGuid(), d => { });

    }

    public void Save(IAggregate aggregate, Guid commitId, Action<IDictionary<string, object>> updateHeaders)
    {
        var commitHeaders = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    {CommitIdHeader, commitId},
                    {AggregateClrTypeHeader, aggregate.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName}
                };
        updateHeaders(commitHeaders);

        var streamName = this.streamNamingConvention.GetStreamName(aggregate.GetType(), aggregate.Identity);
        var newEvents = aggregate.GetUncommittedEvents().Cast<object>().ToList();
        var originalVersion = aggregate.Version - newEvents.Count;
        var expectedVersion = originalVersion == 0 ? ExpectedVersion.NoStream : originalVersion - 1;
        var eventsToSave = newEvents.Select(e => ToEventData(Guid.NewGuid(), e, commitHeaders)).ToList();

        if (eventsToSave.Count < WritePageSize)
        {
            this.connection.AppendToStreamAsync(streamName, expectedVersion, eventsToSave).Wait();
        }
        else
        {
            var startTransactionTask = this.connection.StartTransactionAsync(streamName, expectedVersion);
            startTransactionTask.Wait();
            var transaction = startTransactionTask.Result;

            var position = 0;
            while (position < eventsToSave.Count)
            {
                var pageEvents = eventsToSave.Skip(position).Take(WritePageSize);
                var writeTask = transaction.WriteAsync(pageEvents);
                writeTask.Wait();
                position += WritePageSize;
            }

            var commitTask = transaction.CommitAsync();
            commitTask.Wait();
        }

        aggregate.ClearUncommittedEvents();
    }

    private static EventData ToEventData(Guid eventId, object evnt, IDictionary<string, object> headers)
    {
        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(evnt, serializerSettings));

        var eventHeaders = new Dictionary<string, object>(headers)
                {
                    {
                        EventClrTypeHeader, evnt.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName
                    }
                };
        var metadata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eventHeaders, serializerSettings));
        var typeName = evnt.GetType().Name;

        return new EventData(eventId, typeName, true, data, metadata);
    }
}
```

Comment: Without the code that actually saves the data to disk not much we can say. Double check that you are correctly buffering and using a large enough buffer.

Comment: Fair enough, added code below, as mentioned this is using geteventstore.com eventstore.client v3.0.1 via nuget.

Comment: Well I have no idea about the API, but you do have a `CommitAsync` and wait in the code which sounds like a very bad idea if your events aren't several kb large.

Comment: You're committing thousands of tiny writes per second, which is a nightmare scenario for a SSD. It's a wear-levelling nightmare, too. For every hundred or so bytes that you write out, the disk must erase a 512kB page, copy 511kB from the old sector, and append the few bytes that you are writing.

Comment: When your program burns 100% core then it is *not* being bogged down by the disk.  Also a reason that the disk write rate would be low.  JSON is not exactly a very cheap format, lots of string whacking.  Use a proper profiler.

Comment: Removing the WaitAsync it is way, way faster. Need to read on c# async programming. Valid points regarding the SSD, but dont have nightmares as to whats going on - FYI the event store chunks files within solid 256MB file chunks so it will not nuke the SSD!

Comment: The file structure of EventStore unfortunately has nothing to do with the mentioned "write commit spam". EventStore HAS to commit it's write to disk and thus the small write HAS to be written, no matter the size and since SSDs work the way they do, they have to write the whole 512kB page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was partially mentioned in the comments, but to enhance on that, as you are working fully single-threaded in the mentioned code (though you use async, you are just waiting for them, so effectively working sync) you are suffering from latency and overhead for context switching and EventStore protocol back and forth. Either really go the async route, but avoid waiting on the async threads and rather parallelize it (EventStore likes parallelization because it can batch multiple writes) or do batching yourself and send, for example, 20 events at a time.